# Get value without onclick

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I want to make a WhatsApp share button for my Android app. All is set, the only problem is that I can get the textarea value only when I click on a button:

```
<button onclick="GetValue ();">Get the value of the textarea!</button>
```

I want to `GetValue();` without the `onclick`.

This is my WhatsApp code:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send" data-text="GetValue ();" data-href="" class="wa_btn wa_btn_s" style="display:none">Share</a>
```

I want the textarea value in the `data-text` attribute and I am using it like above but it doesn’t work.

This is my textarea:

```
<textarea id="input_output" style="width:95%;" rows="10" wrap="soft">Enter Text Here..
</textarea>
```

Is there any way to get the value without clicking the button?

This is my function:

```
GetValue () {
    var area = document.getElementById ("input_output");
    alert (area.value);
}
```

Comment: Try to bind a `mousedown` or `touchstart` event on the link to set the `data-text` attribute with `document.getElementById("input_output").value`.

Comment: Your function isn’t even _returning_ the value. It’s just alerting it.

Comment: how to return the value ? sorry i dont know much about JS :( @Xufox

Comment: `return area.value;`. Seriously, just Google basic JS documentation / introduction if you’re going to write JS code.

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript

```
document.getElementById("input_output").value
```

Using jQuery

```
$('#input_output').val();
```

**EDIT:**

Probably misunderstood, but it's very hard to understand your question.
As a javascript click event always fires before the "href" sets in, you can set the value when the link is clicked.

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-text', $('#input_output').val());

    return true;
});
```

Comment: The OP's question was "Is there any way to get the value without clicking the button?". I can see that I misunderstood a little, and I edited my answer, but no need to downvote though.

Comment: Yes, there is a need to downvote. If you misunderstood, the answer is wrong and not useful. I don’t blame _you_ for misunderstanding. But _the answer_ is still wrong and wrong answers should be downvoted. I undid the downvote after your edit.